# Send userID in method or send Token

Tags: angularjs, security, token, jwt

I have a concern on, how do I need to send the userID to map an entity:

Assuming that i am using angular or react or whatever front page framework, how do i need to send the userID on the entity.
For example, if the user is creating a Product, My Options are:

1)Send the Product with the userID:

- My back-end will search the user by userID
- set the user in the product.

2)Send the product with the user Token:

- My back-end will validate the token.
- get from the jwt the userID that is in the claim.
- Search the user by the id
- Set the user in the product

What is the best option to do this?
I think that if I send the userID explicity from the front-page, will be a security issue, instead of sending the token.

Comment: Both, send token + userId and validate them together.

Comment: The idea is  send the userID inside the token claim? and when i verify the token I get the userID?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is insecure. Someone might send another userId.  Second one has some security problems too but, not as bad as the first one. And if you have access token, send access token not Id token. Id token is for client side.